# WPF Frame serving cached page

Tags: wpf, xaml, caching

I am writing a help system for a WPF application.  I came up with a system where the content owner will build templates in a simplified XML format that is transformed with XSLT to XAML through an HttpModule in IIS, the generated XAML pages are displayed in a Frame in the client application.  I expose basic functionality to the pages through a View Model, so commands and data are available from the client application.

This works well but my problem is that it seems the Frame is caching the XAML someplace.  For example, if I make a change to the XML, the client continues to display the previous XAML.  If I navigate to the URI in an external browser(IE or Chrome), I can see the new XAML.  Strangely enough, this also causes the Frames cache to be updated with the new XAML.

This caching persists across restarts of the application, my process for development has been, make the change to the XML, navigate to the URI in IE, then navigate in the client application.  This is annoying and also when this goes live I can't have this behavior.

When I am navigating in the page, I am doing it by assigning the URI to the Frame's Source property, like this:

```
instance.Frame.Source = new Uri(instance.WizardUri, instance.PageUri);
```

Any ideas on what could be causing this?